# removing previous .git folder from cache

Tags: git

I'm putting files from an old project within a new one.

I cloned a git repository into a folder, which I copied into another git repository folder, and made the appropriate initial changes, which I was NOT tracking. I want to push all of the files to the new git repository. I tried to add this:

```
$ git add old/*
```

to which I get back:

```
fatal: Path 'old/conf' is in submodule 'old'
```

I tried to delete the whole oldsoft/.git folder (I have the new .git folder within the parent folder), but it still gives me the same error when I try to add oldsoft/*. I think I need to remove the .git information from the cache, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git rm --cached old
git add old
```